Cardano-node fully synced but very high CPU load
I moved my deadalus node to debian VM with 12 Xeon E5-2660 v4 cores and 20GiB of RAM.
But after it fully synced, the CPU load is even higher, constantly at 95-100%, dropping to 0 for a few minutes, and then back to max load.
https://prnt.sc/AoWJVQK_Nwf4
What could be the issue?
